# Parent div height doesn't animate when css transform scale is applied on child div

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

So i've been trying to get the parent div to auto-scale to the height of the combined child divs.

The child divs are resized with the css method

```
.child{
 transform:scale(1);
 transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1) all;
}
```

The parent div does scale, but the scaling is very abrupt & janky.

I have attached a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mabpwa) of the problem.

When you toggle the switch, the child div will scale(0) to scale(1) but the parent div waits for a second then jerks to the full height of the combined child div.

The reason i want to use transform: scale() is because the [performance is better](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/03/18/css-animations-and-transitions-performance/) compared to transitioning height.

Answer (score 0):

## Overflow

just set overflow to auto in the parent div like this

```
#parent {
    width:1300px
    overflow: auto;  
}
```